# case transform with SAS

Tags: sas

I have tables on SAS with the configuration below , although with many more variables:

```
date    var12   var41
2013M8  -25.6   -30
2013M9  -24.5   -27.3
2013M10 -26.4   -25.7
2013M11 -32.6   -29.2
2013M12 -30.7   -27.3
2014M01 -29.2   -30.3
```

I'm trying to put them like this:

```
var12(t0) var12(t-1) var12(t-2)  var41(t0) var41(t-1) var41(t-2)
-29.2     -30.7     -32.6        -30.3     -27.3      -29.2
-30.7     -32.6     -26.4        -27.3     -29.2      -25.7
-32.6     -26.4     -24.5        -29.2     -25.7      -27.3
-26.4     -24.5     -25.6        -25.7     -27.3      -30
```

This is part of the autoregression , where there is a case transform. I've checked internet on how to do that but not with a stellar success so far.

Please not I'm not trying to do an auto regression , only transforming the data to apply a method later on.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A side by side merge does this efficiently.  Basically you just take the same dataset 3 times, but two of those times chop off the first or first two rows with FIRSTOBS (so it starts at row 2 or row 3).  You use rename so the variables don't overwrite each other, and there you go.

The merge without a BY statement is called a side-by-side merge, and just takes a row from each dataset, then moves onto the next row of each dataset.

```
data have;
input date  $  var12   var41;
datalines;
2013M8  -25.6   -30
2013M9  -24.5   -27.3
2013M10 -26.4   -25.7
2013M11 -32.6   -29.2
2013M12 -30.7   -27.3
2014M01 -29.2   -30.3
;;;;
run;

data want;
merge   have(rename=(var12=var12_t2 var41=var41_t2) in=h1) 
        have(firstobs=2 rename=(var12=var12_t1 var41=var41_t1) in=h2) 
        have(firstobs=3 rename=(var12=var12_t0 var41=var41_t0) in=h3);
        if h1 and h2 and h3;
run;
```

If you have a BY group (like an ID) you may need to manipulate it some to make that work.

Comment: Edited to add a few comments about how it works.  It's pretty straightforward, as long as you don't have any sort of by group that messes things up (like wanting to do it for multiple IDs or something).

Comment: Hi Joe,

Quite powerful SAS... 

However, learning curve obliged, I would have a few questions for you.

1) What means `in=h1`?
2) What means `if h1 and h2 and h3`? Could I have the command without them?

Sorry for these questions, just learning to have a better understanding.

Comment: Those are for the purpose of identifying which dataset a row came from.  They're what makes us get 4 rows instead of 6 from the above (they are used to get rid of the partial rows that don't have all three looks).  If you want do get those partial rows, then get rid of the `if` statement (the `in` can either go or stay, they'd be irrelevant then).

Comment: This is a great technique Joe - I'll be adding that to my bag of tricks for sure.  In certain situations this will be a great alternative to using the retain or lag approaches.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks again for your answer. I asked to a few mates of mine who were a bit knowledgeable about SAS. One of them came with the `lag`function. I've checked on the net and it seems to be doing the same thing as the merge. My question is, without disrespect to your help but because I'm learning : Why did you not use the `lag`? 

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Because my solution is easier than lag.  I rarely find use for lag; most of the time, there is an easier way to do that.  It's not actually doing the same thing as merge; it's setting up a queue.  You'd need several more statements to accomplish the same thing with lag.

Comment: Many thanks Joe. After talking with many people around, `lag` is actually not advised. Learning is rough ! : )

Comment: There are times where lag is possibly the best way, or at least the easiest way.  Just not this one.  All tools are useful for their purposes. :)

Comment: Thanks Joe for your answer. True what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

After some time on it, I did the following:

```
data have;
input date  $  var12   var41;
datalines;
2013M8  -25.6   -30
2013M9  -24.5   -27.3
2013M10 -26.4   -25.7
2013M11 -32.6   -29.2
2013M12 -30.7   -27.3
2014M01 -29.2   -30.3
;;;;
run;
```

/*we change the date*/

```
data a_want;
set have;
nouv_date=mdy(substr(date,6,2),01,substr(date,1,4));
format nouv_date monyy5.;
drop date;
run;
```

*/ we do it for a1 to a6/*

```
data a1; set a_want;
run;
```

*/ we do it for a1 to a6/*

```
data a6;
set a5;
proc sql;
delete from a6 where nouv_date=(select max(nouv_date) from a6);
quit;


data a; 
merge a1(rename=(var12=var12_t0 var41=var41_t_0)) 
a2(rename=(var12=var12_t_1 var41=var41_t_1)) 
a3(rename=(var12=var12_t_2 var41=var41_t_2)) 
a4(rename=(var12=var12_t_3 var41=var41_t_3)) 
a5(rename=(var12=var12_t_4 var41=var41_t_4))
a6(rename=(var12=var12_t_5 var41=var41_t_5)); 
by nouv_date;
run;
```

I wanted to put that, in case there will be people who will have a look. It is a bit different from what I've asked first hand but anyway. I hope it will help.

You can imagine as well that some part of it still has to be automated but it is a different part.

Maybe not the most elegant but I did piece by piece, with your help , especially you, Joe.

Cheers.

PS : I know it is not very efficient but long story